# Boost.MPL complexity

Tags: c++, boost, complexity-theory, boost-mpl

The [`boost::mpl::push_back`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/push-back.html) documentation states that:

> push_back performs an insertion at the end of the sequence with 
>   guaranteed O(1) complexity.

Is it complexity of compilation time?

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course. It works with types, not with values.

**The Boost.MPL library is a general-purpose, high-level C++ template metaprogramming framework of compile-time algorithms, sequences and metafunctions**

Answer (score 0):

The `O(1)` refers to complexity during runtime. Usually, procedures which execute in `O(1)` time are said to execute in *constant time*. In this case, the documentation claims that the time needed for push_back to execute is *constant* with respect to the length of the list; that is, its execution time will be a fixed constant time independent of the list's length.

On the other hand, if the documentation had claimed that push_back executed with `O(n)` complexity, that would have indicated that push_back's execution time could be approximated by a linear function of the list's length, where the list's length here is `n`. Functions that fall in this complexity category are said to execute in *linear time*.

Wikipedia has a good introduction to the `O(n)` notation [1]. A good introductory text is "An Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Lieverson, and Rivest.

- [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_oh_notation.
- [2] [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation about O-notation. I was confused that this runtime parameter was applied to compiletime methods. For me the question is about terminology. Such things don't actually executes in runtime. I mean we could say that keyword 'class' takes O(1) as well.